# Replace number in the name of attrubute per variable (java)

Tags: java, android

In my app I have several groups of variables attributes with their own code. How to replace number in the name of attrubute per variable. For insance, from `File t1butF = new File("/data/data/app.myapp/t1but.png");` to `File t[i]butF = new File("/data/data/app.myapp/t[i]but.png");`

Comment: I think that is not posible, bit you can use an array

Answer (score 1):

why don't you create it as array ?

just like

```
File buttonF[] = new File[10];
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    buttonF[i] = new File("/data/data/app.myapp/t" + i + "but.png");
}
```

Comment: I will create, I just didn't know how. Now i see how to do it with the file-adress, but what about attribute name - t1butF? I need t[i]butF, not tbutF[i]. Is it possible?

Comment: answer is "no" for Array, if you want like t[i]butF, you need to write it manually for each line, like t1butF = ..., t2butF = .... , t3butF = ....

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to create an ArrayList like this:

```
List<File> myList = new ArrayList<File>();
```

and to loop through it like this:

```
for(int i=0; i <= 10; i++){
    //do some stuff
    //for example:
    myList.add(new File("/data/data/app.myapp/t" + Integer.toString(i) + "but.png"));
}
```

In fact, you could also use Arrays but Lists can do much more than Arrays and their size don't have to be predefined.

Comment: Did you try your code before posting it? Especially `i.toString()` part.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am working in different languages right now and switching between them instantly is a bit confusing, but now it should work.